# Why are string passed as ArrayLists

Tags: powershell

If I define a function

```
function GetTypeOfParam { 
   Param($input)
   "Type of `$input is $($input.GetType())" 
}
```

Why does it not return a `System.String` when called like this?

```
PS C:\> GetTypeOfParam "a"
```

> Type of $input is System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Comment: More info in the linked duplicate. Short answer: `$input` is an automatic (pre-defined) variable with a specific purpose, so you shouldn't use it for your own purposes as it will give unpredictable results.

Comment: Ah, magic name. Thanks!